# Table cells are being stripped from partial view

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an AJAX call that replaces a table row with the contents of a partial view.

Here's the link with the AJAX call...

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Create Promise",
"CreatePromise",
new { id = Model.bookings.bookingid },
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "insertedpromise",
    OnSuccess = "postmessage('Promise_Created_')"
},
    new { @class = "primaryButton" })
```

this is the target of the AJAX call...

```
<tr id="insertedpromise">
    <td></td>
</tr>
@if (Model.promises.Any())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.promises.Count; i++)
    {
    <tr id="promise_@Model.promises[i].promiseid">
        @Html.Partial("_promises", Model.promises[i])
    </tr>
    }
 }
```

And here's the partial...

```
@model salesModel.promise

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        "UpdatePromise",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "UpdatePromises" + Model.promiseid.ToString(),
            OnSuccess = "postmessage('promise_Updated_')"
        }))
{
    string thisdivid = "UpdatePromises" + Model.promiseid.ToString();

    <div id="@thisdivid">
        @Html.Hidden("promiseid", Model.promiseid)
        @Html.Hidden("bookingid", Model.bookingid)
        @Html.Hidden("updatedate", DateTime.Now)
        <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink(" ",
            "DeletePromise", new { promiseid = Model.promiseid },
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                Confirm = "Delete?",
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnSuccess = "postmessage('promise_Deleted_" + Model.promiseid + "')"
            }, new { @class = "buttondelete" })
            <input type="submit" class="promisebtn btnupdate" value=" " />
        </td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.monetary)</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.note)</td>
        <td>@String.Format("{0:d}", Model.updatedate)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(c => c.updatedby)</td>
     </div>

}
```

Its been painful to try and get the inserted partial to go into the existing table, but the problem right now is...

**when a date field is included - @Html.Hidden("updatedate", DateTime.Now) in this case - all table cells are stripped from the rendered html **

It would seem that the script that MVC injects to render the input field with the calendar control is the issue. Any ideas?

Also, there are many combinations of div tags and other minor subtleties that will cause the same problem. In different scenarios, **the rendering engine renders the partial without the table cells**

Comment: Unless the website is used to literally displaying a list of "promises", I find the use of the term *promise* (which is used in JQuery for async operation promises) confusing (more than usual) :) What is a promise in this context?

Comment: They are promises made to clients by sales staff. I can change it for the sake of jquery, but this happens in other cases as well.

Comment: Ah, if it's sale staff promises just rename them globally to *lies* :) Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be the divs that lie outside of the table cells. I reworked things to get rid of those divs and moved everything inside table cells except the form. I have this working in two scenarios now by removing the divs.